# Prevent duplicate layers in OpenLayers 3

Tags: geoserver, openlayers

After I created a map in OpenLayers 3 (with GeoServer), when I zoomed it out, it duplicated all layers as you can see in the following example:

http://openlayers.org/en/v3.2.1/examples/drag-rotate-and-zoom.html

I don't want the user to be able to drag the map left/right till infinity.

How can I set the extent (to the whole world) so I will not see the duplicated layers?

Comment: By setting maxZoom. Have you read the [docs](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/apidoc/ol.View.html)

Comment: set maxZoom/minZoom does not resolve the problem. you can still drag the map to the right/left with no limit

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the `wrapX:false` parameter during layer source initialisation. For the specific example you mentioned this is not possible as Mapquest tile layer does not use such attribute. But for OSM, Bing and any wms tile source your task can be achieved using the `wrapX:false` parameter.

Comment: happy xmas amigo!!!!!